# wordpress <!--more--> not rendering a link

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the `<!--more-->` tag in my wordpress copy to create an excerpt from the main content and also echo a link, however it is totally disregarding this tag and just posting the full article, below is hope I am implementing it in my templates,

`<?php the_content("Read more about this article..."); ?>` am I doing something wrong? Currently it is showing the while post when I use the above code, however it is my belief that it should only only show everything above the `<!--more-->` tag?

Answer (score 2):

As per the official [WordPress support site](http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/more-tag/):

From the use of your PHP code, it looks like you want to use the `more` tag on pages. `More` works with blog posts but not [pages](http://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/). Please add the following code to your document **above** your PHP line you provided to make it work:

```
<?php
global $more;
$more = 0;
?>
```

Also, be sure that you are not simply in preview mode and that you have actually published the article and previewed it:

> [T]he more tag is not displayed in post previews, since previews display
>   posts in entirety, but the more tag will appear once the post has been
>   published.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using custom page template to display archives. "More" tag doesn't work in pages. If you want to [turn it on in Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#How_to_use_Read_More_in_Pages)...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php the_content("Read more about this article..."); ?>
```

you should use the code like this if you wanna show the  to work in a page

```
<?php
global $more; 
$more = 0;
the_content("Read more about this article..."); 
?>
```